# How to make an angle smooth

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Suppose we are given in $R^2$ an angle ACB and a circle centered at C, like the following picture shows.[image]

How can we "draw" a $C^1$ curve containing the segments outside of the circle and the part AB would be inside the circle and angle at the same time?

Comment: If $C$ is really the center of the circle (contrary to how things look in the diagram), you could use an [circle orthogonal to $\bigcirc C$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalCircles.html). Such a circle is easy to construct: its center is where the tangents at $A$ and $B$ (that is, the perpendiculars to $\overline{CA}$ and $\overline{CB}$ at $A$ and $B$) meet, and it passes through $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Is it $C^1$ for sure?

Comment: $C^1$, yes: the derivative is continuous because the circle is tangent to the angle's rays. The result is not $C^2$, however: it is enough to observe that curvature changes abruptly (from zero to non-zero).

Comment: Yes you are right and it is the simplest $C^1$ curve to draw!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily solve for a quadratic polynomial that will make this $C^1$ (or, indeed, a quartic polynomial that will make it $C^2$). Just take $y=f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, set $f(\pm x_0)=0$ and $f'(\pm x_0) = \mp m$. You have to specify $x_0$ and $m$ appropriately to make sure the curve stays below $C$. (Here I'm taking the $x$-coordinate of $C$ to be $0$ and the $x$-coordinates of $A$ and $B$ to be $\pm x_0$ respectively.)

Comment: Interesting that the quadratic $f(x)=\frac{-mx^2}{2x_0}+mx_0/2$ would fix the problem and the arc of a circle tangent to the angle actually does not...

Comment: Well, for certain values of $x_0$ and $m$, an arc of a circle will work :)

Comment: Thanks Ted,  I will check it!

Answer (score 2):

I present to you: the [Bézier Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

We parameterize the curve with a time value $t$ that varies from $0$ to $1$.  Then, to find a point on the curve, we generate points:
$$D_t = (1-t)A+tC$$
$$E_t = (1-t)C+tB$$
$$F_t = (1-t)D_t+tE_t$$

The locus of $F_t$ as we vary $t$ is then our curve.

Here's one Bézier curve, drawn with 16 segments.

[image: A Bézier curve]

If you want more control, you can switch to [rational Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Rational_B%C3%A9zier_curves), which work approximately the same way, but include a weight with each control point.  Then we have, with weights $a$, $b$, and $c$ corresponding to the three control points above: $d_t = (1-t)a + tc$, etc, mirroring the control equations from before.  Then our final points on the curve are $$F^*_t = \frac{F_t}{f_t}$$  This is equivalent to placing our control points in [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) with varying $w$ values.  In all cases with non-zero weights, the resulting curves are tangent to the lines between the control points at the ends.  There is a weight value that makes the curve a circular arc, equal to the sine of half the angle at the center.

Here's a series of rational Bézier curves, with endpoint weights $1$ and center control point weight varying from $0.1$ to $10$.

[image: Animation of a rational Bézier curve]

Comment: probably the "paintbrush" in Windows make use of Bezier curves!

Comment: Interestingly, these *are* the quadratic curves described in Ted Shifrin's answer.  One method of finding the curve is finding the appropriate weight value for the chosen point.

Answer (score 1):

You already have slopes and values of the desired curve at A and B.  Pick a point P inside the circle and below C.

Find a fourth degree polynomials with the given information and you are done.

Comment: Why my 4-degree polynomial should stay inside the angle and circle?

Comment: Your point P is flexible and you may move it up or down  to adjust for possible misbehaviors.